# How to put the constrain of duplicated entries in DynamoDB?

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-table

I am using DynamoDB under Python environment and I would like to use the following DynamoDB as an example:

| id | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 |

1. I would like to have a table that has unique **id** and **time** (not **id** or **time**).
2. I would like to put entries from time to time. I would like the put operation would fail if there is an entry with the same **id** and **time** already exist in the table.

For the second criteria, I would like to know if I need to perform a **get** operation first or I could perform a write operation and, by table design, could raise an exception and then I ignore the exception (because the entry already exist in DynamoDB).

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to have your code use a partition key that is the compound value of id and time separated by something like a hash. Like `1#1`.

You can insert data with a PutItem having a conditional expression to fail if the PK already exists.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also reading some DynamoDB related materials. I would like to know if it would be a good idea to use time as the sort key?

If time is the sort key, would it be possible that I can perform uniquness checking?

Comment: Just checked Local Secondary Indexes, they said **In a DynamoDB table, the combined partition key value and sort key value for each item must be unique**

Comment: You wouldn’t need an LSI. You can use the PK and SK in combination as the unique primary key.

Comment: Thanks. I currently treat DynamoDB as a cache and I need to write 1000 entries per 10 seconds. After using the pricing calculator it seems the price is a bit high, based on the usage pattern. Therefore I switched to Elasticache eventually (faster write and cheaper in my case). But still I would like to thank for your answer.

Comment: During the process I use id as the partition key and time as the sort key. Then I can only have one item per partition key and sort key.